# How to set the accessible name for WPF combobox item or listbox item?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a VS extension project in which we create some UI elements using WPF. I try to set “AutomationProperties” for ComboBox items and ListBox items. (not ComboBox and ListBox themselves)

But the narrator can not announce the “AutomationProperties.Name” for items in ComboBox/ListBox when item is selected. It’s always announcing the class name for the items.

I use “DataTemplate” for the itemtemplate like:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVBuR.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdNEI.png)

And I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Override the ToString() method of the class which you use as your ItemsSource objects, in your case the "Trigger" class.
2. Just set the "DisplayMemberPath" in the Combobox to "Id". Add a style for the "ItemContainerStyle" for setting the "AutomationProperties.Name" property. Example:

```
<Combobox ItemsSource={Binding Triggers} SelectedValue={Binding SelectedTrigger} DisplayMemberPath="Id">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding Id}" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```